# Why is my canvas centered on the right side instead of the canvas center?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html and JavaScript but I am having an issue just as the title describes.  It seems that the right side of my canvas is centering on the canvas-wrap div I have created.  I have tried many different ways of centering this canvas to no avail.  HELP PLZ!

link to what it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL0x2.jpg

This is just a simple canvas displaying on a webpage in html and js.  I have tried to use js solution to center the canvas based on height/width of viewport as well as many common css techniques found on this website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>First Game basics</title>
<meta name="veiwport" content= "width=device-width">
<style>

    * {box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; padding: 0;}

    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #202888;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    canvas {
    }

    div.canvas-wrap {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        border: 1px solid red;

        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }   

</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Learn some<br>basic canvas<br>manipulation</p>
<div class="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas>Canvas not supported</canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = "#008000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.height, ctx.canvas.width);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works. you are just drawing wrong...

fillRect parameter are (x, y, width, height) but you have inverted the last 2 and you are drawing (x, y, height, width), so you are drawing out of the canvas.

with

```
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

it will work.

also, use the inspector to see DOM element positioning, you would have seen the mistake in 2 second

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewzGwO